# La subconsulta devuelve más de un resultado en un INSERT INTO en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la tabla *zccomerciales* y la tabla *users*. Estoy intentando rellenar el campo *idUsuario* de la tabla *zccomerciales* con los valores *id* de la tabla *users*.

Esta es mi consulta:

```
INSERT INTO zccomerciales (idUsuario)
select id from users where zccomerciales.nombreComercial = users.name;
```

Como hay un total de 15 registros me dice que la subquery devuelve más de un resultado, pero claro, es que necesito rellenar con este valor los campos que el nombre coincida.

> Sé que puedo hacerlo a manija porque solo son 15 registros pero no me parece profesional.

Hay que tener en cuenta que el id de la tabla *users* es su row y *idUsuario* de la tabla *zccomerciales* es foreing key de la *id* tabla *users*.

Comment: "Sé que puedo hacerlo a manija porque solo son 15 registros pero no me parece profesional." esto es un error.. si son solo 15 registros, ya hubieras terminado y hubieras pasado a tu siguiente tarea. La forma profesional de hacer las cosas, es la que de la mejor solucion para el problema, no la solucion mas nerd para el problema ;).. Igual, no entiendo tu problema, necesitaria ver un ejemplo...

Comment: yo creo que en vez de usar un insert deberias usar un update

Answer (score 1):

A lo que entendí quieres insertar un valor en una columna con un **id** ya existente, si esto es correcto, lo que necesitas es realizar un *update* a la tabla con los valores deseados, tu consulta entonces sería:

```
UPDATE zccomerciales 
SET idUsuario = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE zccomerciales.nombreComercial = users.name);
```

Answer (score -2):

El mensaje de error te indica que la subconsulta devuelve más de un resultado, por que tienes más de un usuario o comercial con el mismo nombre.